# ember.js - Binding in the context of the current class

Tags: ember.js

I have an array controller that creates another object in a computed property as specified below:

```
App.MyArrayController = Ember.ArrayController.extend
  prop: ( ->
    OtherClass.create
      content: Ember.Object.create
        user: @get('currentUser')
        referenceBinding: 'model' 
  ).property('model.[]')
```

The referenceBinding above is not being bound to the ArrayController's content.

Should this be possible or is there a way of binding the content to a property of the OtherClass instance?

Answer (score 0):

I guess this could be easily achieved if you pass in the controller, so that the object can get a hold on your Controller:

```
var that = this;
OtherClass.create({
    content: Ember.Object.create({
        user: this.get('currentUser'),
        referenceBinding: 'reference.model',
        reference : that //=> the controller
    })
});
```